# IG Trading API, Market Order Not Working. ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, request, trading

After logging in I am trying to trade on my demo spread betting account, Wall Street and after many EPIC attempts and changing values I keep reciveving the same error:

My Body:

```
const bodyS = {
    "epic": "IX.D.DOW.IFS.IP",
    "expiry": "-",
    "direction": "BUY",
    "size": 1,
    "orderType": "MARKET",
    "guaranteedStop": true,
    "stopDistance": 30,
    "forceOpen": true,
    "limitDistance": 30,
    "currencyCode": "GBP",
    }
```

Then I get the deal ID back and a 200 OK

But after that I get this repose from deal/confirms/

```
{
  date: '2022-07-11T11:14:38.476',
  status: null,
  reason: 'ATTACHED_ORDER_LEVEL_ERROR',
  dealStatus: 'REJECTED',
  epic: 'IX.D.DOW.IFS.IP',
  expiry: null,
  dealReference: 'Z567CEH5GSCTYPT',
  dealId: 'DIAAAAJZUJ9YVAH',
  affectedDeals: [],
  level: null,
  size: null,
  direction: 'BUY',
  stopLevel: null,
  limitLevel: null,
  stopDistance: null,
  limitDistance: null,
  guaranteedStop: false,
  trailingStop: false,
  profit: null,
  profitCurrency: null
}
```

Help if You Can.

Comment: Did you solve your issue ? I have the same problem

Comment: Contacted, the IG trading, forgot the soultion, but it has something to with, the EPIC's, as they are wrong on the web application, you need to request the list, ask the support team.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues. You have set a limit distance, but a market order type. And the epic is wrong. "IX.D.DOW.IFS.IP" is the CFD epic, for a spread bet it should be "IX.D.DOW.DAILY.IP".

Check the documentation [here](https://labs.ig.com/rest-trading-api-reference/service-detail?id=678)